Can Windows BCrypt perform RSA decryption (not verification) with a public key?
Edit: To bear clear, the encrypted buffer was encrypted with the private key.  I am trying to decrypt, with the public key, data that was encrypted with the private key.
I'm trying to perform RSA decryption with a public key using the BCrypt API, but BCryptDecrypt always returns STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER.  Does BCrypt not allow decrypt with a public key?
Some error checking and resource cleanup removed for brevity.  BCryptDecrypt is where I receive a failure status.
BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE bcrypt_alg = nullptr;
BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE bcrypt_pub_key = nullptr;
NTSTATUS status = 0;

status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
    &bcrypt_alg,
    BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,
    nullptr,
    0);

status = BCryptImportKeyPair(
    bcrypt_alg,
    nullptr,
    BCRYPT_PUBLIC_KEY_BLOB,
    &bcrypt_pub_key,
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&rsa_pub_key),
    sizeof(rsa_pub_key),
    0);

BCRYPT_PKCS1_PADDING_INFO padding_info = { 0 };
ULONG output_size = 0;
status = BCryptDecrypt(
    bcrypt_pub_key,
    (PUCHAR)encrypted,
    (ULONG)encrypted_size,
    &padding_info,
    nullptr,
    0,
    nullptr,
    0,
    &output_size,
    BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    printf("Failed to decrypt, error 0x%x\n", status);
    return false;
}

unsigned __int8 * decrypted = new unsigned __int8[output_size];

status = BCryptDecrypt(
    bcrypt_pub_key,
    (PUCHAR)encrypted,
    (ULONG)encrypted_size,
    &padding_info,
    nullptr,
    0,
    decrypted,
    output_size,
    &output_size,
    BCRYPT_PAD_PKCS1);
if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    printf("Failed to decrypt, error 0x%x\n", status);
    return false;
}

...


No, can't. With public rsa key you can only encrypt data or verify signature

@RbMm do you mean to say I can't using bcrypt?  I have been able to accomplish this with OpenSSL, and the RFC I am implementing is instructing me to decrypt with a public RSA key.

Does this Q&A match your problem?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk RFC 2315.  To clarify, I am trying to decrypt data that was encrypted with the private key.

@IInspectable Fair question, but no.  I must parse the decrypted value of encryptedDigest in a PKCS SignerInfo structure.

Signature verification in RSA is decrypting with the public key.  1) generate MAC, 2) encrypt the MAC with your private key, 3) receiver decrypts the digest with your public key.

@Noah If you want to decrypt a hash then you probably want to verify using PKCS#1 padding (for verification, not encryption). The idea in your ancient RFC that signature verification is decryption of the hash followed by hash comparison has long since been removed from the PKCS#1 and PKCS#7 or CMS RFC's.

@IanBoyd No signature verification is not decryption with the public key. And you don't use a MAC you'd use a hash function. If you don't know that a MAC isn't used for asymmetric signatures then please don't try and teach others, learn yourself.

Currently we don't know how the signature (I presume it is not actually a ciphertext) was generated. Could you indicate what was used? I'd hope for PKCS#1 padding for signature generation was used and then it is possible to simply verify. Otherwise you may need to do a raw decrypt and remove the padding yourself. This is harder, but the solution space is probably not empty. Decryption with a public key is not standardized though (why should it?) so different libraries are going to react differently, if they allow it at all.

@MaartenBodewes The encrypted data is an ANS1 structure, as defined by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2315#section-9.4

@MaartenBodewes That's the latest RFC, by the way.  Regardless of age PKCS 7 version 1.5 is still widely used.

No, PKCS#7 is the name of the standard. CMS is the container format it defines. RSA labs isn't around anymore, and they created their own standards. Nobody should be using those anymore, we're using those defined by the IETF now. The only reason that the later CMS standards do not obsolete this ancient RFC is because RFC 2315 is simply a reproduction of PKCS#1 by RSA labs. An RFC cannot obsolete standards defined by another standardization body.

@MaartenBodewes The fact that this RFC is still used is not up to me.  I am not the generator of the data that I have to decrypt, my job is simply to do so.

@MaartenBodewes in one particular instance, the decrypted data looks like this when decoded as ASN1:
SEQUENCE
  SEQUENCE
    ObjectIdentifier sha256 (2 16 840 1 101 3 4 2 1)
    NULL
  OCTETSTRING 981daf0addd65a8182607f476496e474620a84d0c3448d1413581f875c5e7204..(total 32bytes)..981daf0addd65a8182607f476496e474620a84d0c3448d1413581f875c5e7204


Ah no, it is the signature itself that can be a BIT or OCTET STRING. Never mind, this is just a PKCS#1 signature. Use verification.

@MaartenBodewes I understand, but I want to be able to parse the asn1 myself.  I understand that I could do verification, but that's not what this question is about.

If you want to do it yourself then you should use the flag BCRYPT_PAD_NONE obviously. Note that this does also leave the other padding, but that's easy enough to verify & strip if you take a look at the PKCS#1 standard (whichever version). Again for signing / verifying. It may still not work, again, depends on the library. Otherwise use any other bignum lib that offers modular exponentiation.

"It is often mentioned that signing is equivalent to RSA encrypting (the hash over) the message using the private key. This is only true if you disregard the required padding mechanism. The RSA padding mechanisms are different for encryption and signing." In other words you encrypt with your private key your suitably prepared blob, that the receiver will decrypt with your public key to verify that it was indeed you who "signed" (i.e. encrypted with private key) the blob used to verify the message.

Does BCrypt not allow decrypt with a public key? No, BCryptDecrypt() requires a private key, a public one results in a STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER error (not even BCRYPT_PAD_NONE helps here). Nor is it possible to encrypt with a private key. Although BCryptEncrypt() is executed with a private key, actually here the public key is extracted from the private key under the hood and a regular encryption is performed with the extracted public key (which also implies that for BCryptDecrypt() a public key would be pointless and a private key is required instead).

@IanBoyd: In my experience, it just adds confusion to use the word encryption in the context of signing. It used to be more common to see things referred to that way 25 years ago but now it is not so common.

I find it the exact opposite; i find it simplifying to know that "encrypting" and "signing" are two sides of the same coin.

The PKCS#1 RFCs (e.g. RFC8017) define the padding as part of the process (of encrypting/signing) and do not reduce the process to mere exponentiation. In this sense, the formulas Signing = Encryption with the private key / Verifying = Decryption with the public key are at least not compliant with the specification.
